# @commands.Cog.listener() on_ready(self) not responding

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a code as such in my cog, which should create a file `amounts.db` in my `data` folder with the relevant table inside once my bot is loaded up

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_ready(self):
    dbamounts = await aiosqlite.connect("data//amounts.db", self.bot.loop)
    camounts = dbamounts.cursor()
    await camounts.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Amounts(id INTEGER, balance INTEGER, UNIQUE(id))")
    await dbamounts.commit()
    store["dbamounts"] = dbamounts
    store["camounts"] = camounts
```

Even when I tried other commands such as just printing, it doesn't work

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_ready(self):
    print("Ready!")
```

Every other code works, @commands.command() and all, just not the @commands.Cog.listener() tagged codes. Is there possibly something wrong with my installation of discord.py, and if so, how should I reinstall it?

Comment: This looks fine, and works on mine.  just to be sure, this listener is actually inside of a cog?  and can you run your bot with the printing listener and post the output?

Comment: @bravosierra99 It was, I figured the issue out though. I was loading my cogs on_ready as well in my main file. It worked when I just shifted to load the cogs before that!

Comment: good job figuring it out!  any particular reason you are waiting to load your cogs until then?  Feel like you could run into some weird edge cases where (rarely) where your cogs are not loaded when your bot connects.

Comment: @Childisher thanks for the comment - you saved my Discord bot! As a note for people in the future, I had to put the cog loading in an `asyncio.run()` to allow it to be loaded outside of an async method. Here's some example code: https://github.com/2br-2b/StoryBot/blob/eaf7df07e4eacc870453748ccc0549da1a319e9a/main.py#L61-L70. You should put this as an answer to your own question rather than leaving it as only a comment.